# Program is having issues with inputting arrays

Tags: java

The output for the following code is:
Please enter your words:
hello, keshav, bob, doan
kehsavbob
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "kehsavbob"
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:786)
at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:101)

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Read in the method name that we want to call
        System.out.print("Please enter your words: ");
        String methodName = sc.nextLine();
        // Read in number of words
        int numWords = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        // Read in list of words
        String[] words = new String[numWords];
        for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
            words[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        sc.close();

        // Run the specified method
        switch (methodName) {
            case MIN_METHOD_NAME:
                System.out.println(minWordLength(words));
                break;
            case MAX_METHOD_NAME:
                System.out.println(maxWordLength(words));
                break;
            case RANGE_METHOD_NAME:
                System.out.println(wordLengthRange(words));
                break;
            case AVERAGE_METHOD_NAME:
                System.out.println(averageWordLength(words));
                break;
            case MODE_METHOD_NAME:
                System.out.println(mostCommonWordLength(words));
                break;
            default:
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
```

}

Comment: Welcome! Please note that this site is not a debugging service. Copy-pasting large slabs of code into the question and asking us to debug it is off-topic. However, we can help you with *specific* questions about small *parts* of your code (a few lines), ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to narrow its focus and remove all code not directly relevant and absolutely required to describe your problem.

Comment: if you want input "hello, keshav, bob, doan kehsavbob""  you need to split  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
          // Read in the method name that we want to call
        System.out.print("Please enter your words: ");
        String methodName = sc.nextLine();
        // Read in number of words
       System.out.println("method name" + methodName);
        sc.close();
       String [] words = methodName.split(",");

Comment: @sjy Where do I include the for loop to loop through if I am already closing the scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to parse an integer from a word, which won't work.

Replace:

```
int numWords = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
String[] words = new String[numWords];
```

with:

```
String[] words = sc.nextLine().split("\W+");
```